# How to load a file created by MySQL dump?

Tags: mysql

There is a MySQL dump file ; the file has no extension. How can I import the file into a MySQL database ?

Comment: dump files usually are sql scripts. `type` or `cat` few lines at command prompt and get confirmed.

Comment: the file has no extension , or can I rename it to have sql extension ?

Comment: Do you have mysql command line access? You don't need to change file extension as long as contents are sql queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can rename it as .sql and do

mysql -uuser -ppwd db < /file.sql

As long as the queries are proper it should work